# Custom names and lores in Minecraft 1.7.2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have heard it was possible to change the names and lores of Minecraft items WITHOUT the use of third-party programs like MCEdit. Given the things that my friends have told me, and from the information gathered online, my guess is that, since Minecraft has started using JavaScript, `/give @p 35 1 14 {name:"Red Wool",lore:"bob"}`. Whenever I run this command block, all I get is a piece of Red Wool with no Lore, nor a name. I also get no errors in this process.

Comment: I believe Minecraft actually uses JQuery, iirc. It is possible, for sure. Give me a minute to figure out the actual command.

Comment: Actually, It uses neither. It uses Java, witch is completely different. JSON is a method of describing objects, derived out of Javascript, but used in many different languages. Minecraft nbt in commands are designed to JSON-like.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're close. The command for this particular case would be `/give @p wool 1 14 {display:{Name:"Red Wool",Lore:[Bob]}}`, which results in:

[image: Result of command]

The format for the lore text is in brackets allows you to add new lines by using commas, as well. In this case, the command is `/give @p wool 1 14 {display:{Name:"Red Wool",Lore:[Bob, Joe]}}`. This results in:

[image: Result of command]

You can also include multiple words or `[]` in the lore, but you need to use quotes like `/give @p wool 1 14 {display:{Name:"Red Wool",Lore:["Multiple Words"]}}`. This results in:

[image: Result of command]

This also works with multiple lines. `/give @p wool 1 14 {display:{Name:"Red Wool",Lore:["Multiple Words", "Multiple Lines"]}}` results in:

[image: Result of command]

If you are using quotes in your custom lore or name, escape it with `\` before the quote. An example command that escapes quotes would be `/give @p wool 1 14 {display:{Name:"\"This is in Visible Quotes\"",Lore:["\"Lore with Quotes\""]}}`. You can see the result of that command below:

[image: Result of command]

For more information on all the new special data tags you can use, check out [this post](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1969520-17-using-summon-give-datatags-in-map-making-tutorialswip/) on the Minecraft Forum.

Comment: And here I thought they were referring to renaming something on the anvil.

Comment: You should generally quote your strings, even in arrays