# How do I rename things in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm currently running a Minecraft Realm. I am trying to give people some renamed things, but I have no idea how to rename things. Well, I know how to rename thing with the majestic anvil, but when it comes to colours and non-italic names, I am clueless. I heard of the lore tag and the custom name tag but I don't know how to use it.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **lore** tag can be added without server plugins or mods, more information can be found [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/144746/custom-names-and-lores-in-minecraft-1-7-2).

The basic command for it is:

> /give @p **Insert item type here** 1 14 {display:{Name:"**Insert name here**",Lore:[**Insert lore here**]}}.

This works without any plugins or modifications, and you can display the name as well as the lore with the command.

Comment: -1 Does Minecraft Realms even support Bukkit?!? Because it doesn't.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to say. I'm running a Minecraft Realm which does NOT support any plugins or mods. The very last part (the lore link part) though is very helpful. I'll take that as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think Chantola knows that. @ArceusMaster0493

Comment: @aytimothy I didn't know that, sorry I'm editing it now. Thanks for explaining why the downvote.

Comment: That's better ;) UpVoted

Comment: What should I do if I want to add colours to the name of the item? Do I add another data tag?

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 I'm not sure if you can. I researched for hours and could find nothing about naming with colors, everything I found is a server plugin/mod like bukkit.

Answer (score -1):

You can rename things by using name tags. You put a name tag in the anvil then up there is a little line that u can write the name.

Comment: You can only rename mobs with name tags. Renaming the items in the anvil is the correct way. I down-voted you.