# How can I give a red wool that has a lore, name, and can only be placed on stone?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to know how to  make a red wool block that has a lore, name, and can only be placed on stone. I really want to make an adventure map. I tried

```
 /give @p wool 1 14 {Display:[Name:"<name>",Lore:[<lore>]]}},{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:stone"]}
```

If anyone knows how to make a red wool block that has a lore, name and can only be placed on stone please tell me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/144746/custom-names-and-lores-in-minecraft-1-7-2

Comment: but I need to make it have a name and a lore and can be placed on a certain block instead of just a name and a lore so this isn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issues with your command are:

1. `display` needs to start with a lowercase `d`
2. `display` is a compound tag - `{ }` - rather than a list - `[ ]`
3. Both `display` and `CanPlaceOn` should be in the same top tag, rather than two separate top tags. E.G: `{display:{...},CanPlaceOn:[...]}` rather than `{display:{...}},{CanPlaceOn:[...]}`

Here's the fixed command:

```
/give @p wool 1 14 {display:{Name:"Example",Lore:["One","Two"]},CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:stone"]}
```